# EWS API : Pull subscription GetEvents often slow and gets

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a problem with GetEvents that I find strange and very worrying.

Our client creates a pull subscription (either a new one, or by specifying and old watermark in case of subscription timeout) and every few minutes calls GetEvents to receive changes to the folders in the subscription. Since this is a mobile client, there is a possibility that the client may be inactive for several hours or days between GetEvents. For the most part, this works; clients synchronize the contents of the folders. One problem I have is GetEvents does not return the maximum number of events per call neither return **isMoreEventsAvailable** flag, making it necessary to call GetEvents many times until all the events are received.

Thanks
Krish

Answer (score 0):

This is how EWS Pull Subscriptions are supposed to work. By having the client poll the `GetEvents` method until the `MoreEventsAvailable` flag is false allows Exchange to keep control of how much data it sends out to the calling application.

The subscription will maintain the `Watermark` flag so you can be sure when you poll `GetEvents` till `MoreEventsAvailable` is false you'll get all the events that have happened since last high `Watermark`.